# How to make a method to refer only to the instance of a class given as a parameter for the method?

Tags: java, methods, multiple-instances, vaadin7, object-reference

I'm required to make a quick fix on a class, where a method, that processes files on a dropzone and mails them with a press of a button, gets a Dropzone as a parameter. However there's a bug that there will be multiple instances of the said Dropzone. Each time a window is opened, a new dropzone is created...

Whenever the dropzone validation fails (wrong type of file dragged on it, or pressing the button with no files on the dropzone), there will be as many error windows showing in the client as there are instances of the dropzone.

I know that's a horrible bug made by the guy before me, but right now I would only need to refer to the most recent instance of the said DropZone within the method when making the error window pop-up.

Now, the question is, how can I refer within the method ONLY to the instance of the dropzone which was given as a parameter for the method and ignoring all the underlying other instances of it, thus avoiding the "incrementation" of error windows?

Here's some relevant code:

```
@Inject
private Instance<Toast> toast;

final DropZone dropZone = createDropzone(FORMDOCUMENT, "placeholder");
windowLayout.addComponent(dropZone)

private void processDropzoneFiles(DropZone dropZone) {
...
 if (!dropZone.hasItems()) {
    toast.get().show("Error message"), Toast.ToastType.ERROR);
 }
...
}
```

Comment: You mean you want to clarify the passed object is `DropZone` to the method `processDropZoneFile()` ?

Comment: it will use the one in the parameter by default. or if you have an auto complete feature in your IDE. `CTRL + SPACE` in eclipse you can see that there is a `FINAL` symbol beside the dropZone and the other one doesnt have.

Comment: `I know that's a horrible bug made by the guy before me` :) Isn't it always?

Comment: Sounds like `errorPopUp` should be related to `DropZone` instance, don't know how much refactoring would it take.

Comment: Predrag Maric, the problem is that the errorPopUp is actually a toast. Hmm ,I should mention that in the problem.

Comment: I would just fix the bug. Building special code to live with a bug is a waste of time and only gives the bug longevity. Kill it instead.